# Differential equation question -- what's my next step in finding the differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I posted a while earlier and someone helped me figure the first few steps out of questions like these. I have come across another question:

[image]

So basically, I said that:
$$ L_{in} = 20, L_{out} = -kh^2$$
$$\frac{dV}{dh} = 4h^2, \frac{dV}{dt} = 20 - kh^2$$

I'm not quite sure what my next step is. Does
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dh}  \frac{dh}{dt}$$

apply here? I'm not sure how to get $\frac{dh}{dt}$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since V is a function of h which is a function of time i.e: $V(h(t)) $ , we can apply the chain rule as you've stated:

$$ \frac{dV(h(t))}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dh}|_{h(t)}  \frac{dh}{dt}$$

This means,

$$ \frac{dh}{dt}  = \frac{\frac{dV(h(t))}{dt}}{\frac{dV}{dt}|_{h(t)}} \tag{1}$$

Also remember by conservation of liquid:

$$ dV = dV_{in}  - dV_{out}$$

Or,

$$ \frac{dV(h(t))}{dt} = \frac{dV_{in}}{dt}  - \frac{ dV_{out} }{dt} \tag{2} $$

All you have to do is combined (1) and (2)

Comment: Almost get it. Can you tell me what $\frac{dV}{dh}|_{h(t)}$ means? Is it a limit?

Comment: The equation reads:

"The rate of change of volume with time, is the rate of change of the volume with height times the rate of change of height with time"

Comment: Chain rule: Rates of change multiply under composistion